# remove static noise from audio recording

Tags: audio-recording, noise-reduction, noise-cancelling

I have a recording with a static noise added throughout the audio. the longest silence period I could extract was this:
[audio_file](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0QAT60ZhIH6)

however, it contains some moments of new sounds of flipping pages. The fourier transform of my noise looks like:
[image]

How can I remove this noise from my audio?

Comment: You've got buckets of 60Hz, throw an HPF at it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using a noise reduction tool?

There are plenty available on the market, check-out this article:

[best-noise-reduction-plugins](http://www.sonicscoop.com/2013/05/30/the-best-noise-reduction-plugins-on-the-market/)

Comment: Nothing more to add to this as an answer. Just wanted to point out my favorite NR plugin, that isn't often mentioned: http://www.voxengo.com/product/redunoise/ :)

Comment: @sauli always room for more suggestions :-)